# What happened to reputation when Meta Stack Exchange split from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, mso-mse-split

Recently I came to know that MSE was split from MSO. I am wondering if the reputation of Meta users was duplicated in this new MSE.

1. Was the reputation split or duplicated?
2. Is that why some users have extremely high reputation? (because the Rep in MSE represents the Rep gotten from SO before split)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This site is the *old* Meta Stack Overflow, *renamed* to Meta Stack Exchange, with a fresh graphical design and much of the Stack Overflow specific content cleaned up. An entirely new site was created to become [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), and some content was moved over to it.

The new Meta Stack Overflow site is a regular child Meta, where you do not have an independent reputation. Instead your reputation is copied over from the main site, once every hour.

Meta Stack Exchange is an exception in that it is not a child Meta of a main site, and you earn reputation like on a regular Stack Exchange site here. All older accounts with a lot of reputation here earned it from before the rename.

TL;DR: MSE is the *old site, renamed*, accounts here simply didn't lose reputation. The current MSO is the *new site*, and you don't earn rep there as it is a regular child Meta.

Note that at no point did this site ever share reputation with Stack Overflow! Reputation here has always been separate.

Comment: So reputation of old users in MSE also includes the reputation they got for solving problems in SO. I was wondering how people got extremely high rep, now I know!!

Comment: @CRags Not so. Unlike other child metas, meta.SO had separate reputation from SO in the pre-split era. Users earned  reputation there by participating in meta discussions, etc, same as they do now on meta.SE.

Comment: @Fundamental Well now that clears up the question. If you answer, I will accept it

Comment: @CRags ah, you seem to think Stack Overflow reputation (as opposed to *Meta* Stack Overflow reputation) was shared here. That was never the case. Edited to make that explicit.

Comment: @CRags No need to, Martijn edited in this point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, that was the point of my question. So MSE was renamed but had the same system (process) of reputation even before (meaning reputation was separate). That clears it up for me. Thanks!

Comment: But what about rep from posts migrated back?

Comment: @Scimonster: same as with any post deleted on this site; if it had a score of 3 or up and was 60 days old or older, you kept the reputation. Otherwise it was lost.

Comment: @Scimonster: [example post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250987/magic-link-to-how-to-ask-page#229539) that was migrated; I lost the reputation for my answer here on MSE because at the time of migration it only had a score of +2 and the post was only a few days old; my reputation log shows I lost 35 points (20 for votes + 15 for the accept).